# RxJava flatmap chain skips errors

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2

I have following code

```
repository.operationOne()
            .flatMap {
                repository.operationTwo().map {
                    it.items
                }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        // Success
                    },
                    {
                       // Error
                    })
            .trackDisposable()
```

The problem is that my operationOne() returns error 400 from retrofit but my error block in subscribe is never executed as second api call succeeds. How to stop second api call (operationTwo) if first one failed and invoke error block from subscribe?

**EDIT:** both operations return single. Also adding onErrorResumeNext, doOnError or onErrorReturn doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Try using `onErrorReturn`

Comment: I tried putting it before and after flatmap to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of firstOperation using retrofit with response Single < Response <Void >> which apparently doesn't throw exception on 400 response.